# Missing Visual Studio Function

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I need some help with my Visual Studio layout. I am missing a comfort function but I don't know how to write it exactly. Attached are 2 images. As it looks the desired function is available in C# projects. With VB project this is missing. Resetting the window layout does not bring anything. Can someone help me?

[image: Missing Function]

Comment: See: [Create a Windows Forms app in Visual Studio with Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-a-visual-basic-winform-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 4):

That is the Navigation Bar. Select *Tools* > *Options* from the main menu, select *Text Editor* > *Basic* > *General* in the *Options* dialogue, then check the *Navigation bar* box.

You really ought to have a fairly thorough look through the *Options* dialogue to see what's there and what you might want to change now or in the future. I have answered numerous questions on how to change VS settings simply because I was prepared to do that when the person asking the question didn't bother.